# Как убрать подсвечивание checkbox на ios?

Tags: css

Как убрать стандартное подсвечивание checkbox на ios?

Answer (score 3):

Используй этот набор свойств

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: не помогло к сожалению

Comment: @АнтонШепотько предлагаю приложить код или скриншот для разъяснения ситуации

Comment: -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;  помогло вот это свойство, это было не совсем из за чекбокса